# Referring to sibling object

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I have library object called **mc_menu**, with a class code attached. the class build a menu on stage and puts MCs on stage (and replaces them by the menu clicking).
I'm trying to call an object that was placed from the parent class on stage, but I can't find out the right way of doing that.

The main code sits on main.as
this is the important part of the code:

```
public class main extends MovieClip {
        public function main() {


            //add container layers
            addChild(bottomLayer);
            addChild(topLayer);


            topLayer.addChild(menuInst);
            menuInst.init();

}

     public var menuInst= new mc_Menu;            
    public var topLayer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    public var bottomLayer:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

as you see, I prepearing 2 layers of sprites on the main stage for later use.
the menu should be putted on the top layer (as it does successfully) and the MCs of the item themselfs as long as other objects will be placed inside the bottom layer.

well the problem is like that. I'm trying to tell the menuClass to call the bottom layer and I couldn't find a way to refference it right.

this is the code part:
mcMenu.as

```
public class mc_Menu extends MovieClip {

        public function mc_Menu() {

        }


public function init():void{    
        bottomLayer.addChild(masterChapter);
}
```

I know this can't be done this way because inside the class scope it doesn't know "bottomLayer". but can you please help me how can I do it right?

I prefer leaving the layers instances on the main class (and not taking them inside the menu class) because other elements will use them later. (unless I have no choice...)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the bottomLayer through the parent of the mc_Menu instance, the only reason this is a bad idea is if you plan to re-use the mc_Menu and it will have different parents.  In programming terms the Classes will be tightly coupled but this would be a quick and dirty solution:

```
public function init():void{    
        parent.parent.bottomLayer.addChild(masterChapter);
}
```

A better option is to use a "Singleton" pattern or some sort of dependency injection MVC or MVVM framework like robot legs or SpringAS or something else where you could declare the instances outside of both main and your child elements and have the value/instance injected into both.

**EDIT**

After thinking this through for a second, another option is to pass the instance of the bottomLayer into the mc_Menu when you create it like:

```
public class mc_Menu extends MovieClip {
    private var _bottomLayerHandle:Sprite;
    public function mc_Menu(bottomLayer:Sprite)
    {
        _bottomLayerHandle = bottomLayer;
    }
    public function init():void{    
        _bottomLayerHandle.addChild(masterChapter);
    }
}
```

Then when creating them just re-arrange so the Sprite is made first:

```
public var bottomLayer:Sprite = new Sprite();
public var topLayer:Sprite = new Sprite();
public var menuInst= new mc_Menu(bottomLayer);
```

Comment: Thank you! somewhy I didn't think it need to go 2 steps back (parent.parent) but only one, and that's why parent. didn't worked for me...